# delete end of strings in dataframe

Tags: python, python-3.x, regex, data-cleaning

I have a dataset each cell is like that `-29 25846 0` they ends with  `0` so I want to delete this zero I tried this piece of code but it doesn't work `df[df.columns].applymap(lambda x: x.rstrip(x[-1]))`

Comment: please follow guidelines here in providing enough details to help respond  https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: [How to make good reproducible pandas examples](//stackoverflow.com/q/20109391/843953)

Answer (score 0):

Not having the dataframe, it would be hard to guess what you are dealing with. anyway, code below might give you a better understanding of how to handle such situation:

```py
def strip_zero(value):
  if value[-1] == "0":
    return value[:-1]
  return value
df["sample_column"].apply(strip_zero)
```

This will strip the ending zeros from the *sample_column*

Answer (score 0):

it helps to have a reproducible example, but following will work with the assumption that the data is of this format i.e., ending with zero and may/maynot have space after zero

-29 25846 0

```
df['columns'].replace(r'\d\s*$','', regex=True)
```